# Why R takes 1 raise to power infinity as 1?

Tags: r, math

It is known that 1 raised to power infinity is an indeterminate form in Mathematics. More discussion is available [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10490/why-is-1-infty-considered-to-be-an-indeterminate-form).

In R console,

```
 > (1)^(Inf)
[1] 1
```

I assume that it should produce `NaN`. Please explain the logic behind this output. I am using R version 3.1.2 on windows 7 platform (32-bit system).

Comment: Note that the widely-used IEEE 754 standard for floating-point arithmetic specifies that "pow(1, y) is 1 for any y", and that "pow(x, 0) is 1 for any x".

Comment: See Kahan's paper https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/ieee754status/IEEE754.PDF (particularly page 9) for some discussion on the subject.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `help("^")`:

> 1 ^ y and y ^ 0 are 1, always.

It's useful to output the limit for `1 ^ Inf` more often than not. Returning 1 for `0 ^ 0` is also usually more useful than any alternatives. However, those are basically design decisions.

Comment: Thanks Roland for a prompt reply, but some softwares (for instance MATLAB) produce it as `NaN` which is quite logical.

Comment: Which part of my answer did you not understand? The design decisions made by the Matlab creators are irrelevant here.

Comment: That is true. Anyways, thanks for the reply. I have accepted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There might be historical, and compatibility reasons. R is a varient of S and S dates back to 1976. [S - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S_(programming_language)) R itself was first released in 1993 and compatibility with the commercial [S-Plus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S_(programming_language)) was very important.

S was designed as a statistical language, as such subtilties of the precise meaning of indeterminate forms was not a big issue. Can you give an example of when in a practical statistical application that these forms might occur?

I suspect that in an early version of S, the decicision was made to set 1^(any) = 1, and (any)^0 = 1, 0^(any) = 0, (any)^1 = (any). The precise order in which these statments were implemented might not have been given too much though.

Once the decicision was made its pretty much set in stone. Changing the behaviour then risks breaking third party algorithms. Hence its easier just to go with a convention with little actual consequences.

These conventions get pretty set in stone. Excel get precedence of some operators wrong, but dare not change it for break compatibility.